# Tensorflow android demo got error. Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android, tensorflow, camera

I tried to run `Tensorflow` demo for android.
(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android)
my phone is 22 API level.
I run the demo followed by the instruction. I got fail to connect to camera service error.
I am new to android. How to solve this problem? Give me any clue to solve it.

This error i get

```
12 - 20 16: 29: 20.150 7901 - 7901 / org.tensorflow.demo E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 7901
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.hardware.Camera. < init > (Camera.java: 497)
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java: 342)
at org.tensorflow.demo.LegacyCameraConnectionFragment$1.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(LegacyCameraConnectionFragment.java: 80)
at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java: 370)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java: 14144)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java: 14189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java: 14959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java: 3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java: 3198)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java: 14162)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java: 14189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java: 14959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java: 3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java: 3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java: 15234)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java: 598)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java: 14167)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java: 14189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java: 14959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java: 3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java: 3198)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java: 14162)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java: 14189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java: 14959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java: 3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java: 3198)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java: 14162)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java: 14189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java: 14959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java: 3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java: 3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java: 15234)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java: 598)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java: 2650)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java: 14167)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java: 14189)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java: 273)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java: 279)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java: 318)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java: 2530)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java: 2352)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java: 1982)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java: 1061)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java: 5885)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java: 767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java: 580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java: 550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java: 753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 698)
```

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android
Here is code provided by Google

Answer (score 0):

You might need to **request the permission** at runtime. See [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for more information on this topic. Requesting runtime permissions is required when targeting Android 6.0 or later.